# Aldryn-Django Incompatibilities with Django Versions

Tags: python, django, pip, divio

I've been trying to setup the Divio Cli environment this morning for my project and I do seem to be having so many issues, which is getting quite annoying.  First my pip broke, both versions original and pip3. Now finally at least got pip back on to try and reinstall the requirements needed for the project and now  I occur these issues.

And just to add the top to this, my django project should be at least on 2.2, otherwise I'll need to re-write my code for 1.1. Can anyone find a solution to this apart from using a virtual environment in which I don't use at all?

Bash Logs Below

```
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip install Django==1.11
Collecting Django==1.11
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/a6/078ebcbd49b19e22fd560a2348cfc5cec9e5dcfe3c4fad8e64c9865135bb/Django-1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.9MB 6.5MB/s 
Collecting pytz
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 3.6MB/s 
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 requires pyOpenSSL, which is not installed.
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 has requirement Django==1.6.11, but you'll have django 1.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django
Successfully installed Django-1.11 pytz-2019.3
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip install Django==1.6.11
Collecting Django==1.6.11
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/86/f52eec28e96fb211122424a3db696e7676ad3555c11027afd9fee9bb0d23/Django-1.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 requires pyOpenSSL, which is not installed.
ERROR: django-storages 1.7.2 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.6.11 which is incompatible.
ERROR: aldryn-sites 0.6.0 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.6.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.11
    Uninstalling Django-1.11:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.11
Successfully installed Django-1.6.11
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip recommends
ERROR: unknown command "recommends"
LenovoTP220x Desktop # apt recommends
Usage:  apt recommends [package]
LenovoTP220x Desktop # apt recommends pip
Error: package pip not found in APT cache!
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip install Django==1.11
Collecting Django==1.11
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/a6/078ebcbd49b19e22fd560a2348cfc5cec9e5dcfe3c4fad8e64c9865135bb/Django-1.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from Django==1.11) (2019.3)
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 requires pyOpenSSL, which is not installed.
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 has requirement Django==1.6.11, but you'll have django 1.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.6.11
    Uninstalling Django-1.6.11:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.6.11
Successfully installed Django-1.11
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip install pyOpenSSL
Collecting pyOpenSSL
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/c8/ceb170d81bd3941cbeb9940fc6cc2ef2ca4288d0ca8929ea4db5905d904d/pyOpenSSL-19.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyOpenSSL) (1.10.0)
Collecting cryptography>=2.3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/9a/7cece52c46546e214e10811b36b2da52ce1ea7fa203203a629b8dfadad53/cryptography-2.8-cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.3MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.3MB 4.2MB/s 
Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a8/8d/986e0c4e2aa3b24db56a0affc50d1a379150e3c4da45d51d549dc2697d53/cffi-1.13.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (397kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 8.4MB/s 
Collecting pycparser
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/9e/49196946aee219aead1290e00d1e7fdeab8567783e83e1b9ab5585e6206a/pycparser-2.19.tar.gz (158kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 8.6MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: pycparser
  Building wheel for pycparser (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pycparser: filename=pycparser-2.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=112043 sha256=ba9d8603f660ccef070cc7eeaa471ae98b9f134393fc9e2400764e5559235ca4
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f2/9a/90/de94f8556265ddc9d9c8b271b0f63e57b26fb1d67a45564511
Successfully built pycparser
ERROR: aldryn-django 1.6.11.1 has requirement Django==1.6.11, but you'll have django 1.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL
  Found existing installation: cryptography 1.2.3
    Uninstalling cryptography-1.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled cryptography-1.2.3
Successfully installed cffi-1.13.2 cryptography-2.8 pyOpenSSL-19.0.0 pycparser-2.19
LenovoTP220x Desktop # pip install Django==1.6.11
Collecting Django==1.6.11
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/86/f52eec28e96fb211122424a3db696e7676ad3555c11027afd9fee9bb0d23/Django-1.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: aldryn-sites 0.6.0 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.6.11 which is incompatible.
ERROR: django-storages 1.7.2 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.6.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: Django
  Found existing installation: Django 1.11
    Uninstalling Django-1.11:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-1.11
Successfully installed Django-1.6.11
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue with the Divio CLI might be, but it's not related to the traceback that you show.

There is no need to use virtual environments in Divio projects. When you install packages in a Divio project, they are installed inside a container. You can't do this by running pip in your own environment, which is what I think you are doing.